# java stack peek(),pop() operations not working as expected. (Hacker rank Stack Challenge: Maximum element)

Tags: java, stack

I encountered this problem while solving the Hacker rank Stack Challenge: Maximum element.

I have two stacks named **s** and **max**. 
I need to **delete** the **top element** from stack '**s**'.
If this element deleted from '**s**' is **equal to** the topmost element of  the '**max**' stack,
i need to delete the top element from **max** as well.

I tried both Code 1 and Code 2. Code 1 failed a few test cases while Code 2 passed all the test cases. Can someone explain me the difference in both codes?

### Code 1

```
if(!s.isEmpty()){
    if(s.peek()==max.peek())
        max.pop();
    s.pop();
}
```

### Code 2

```
if(!s.isEmpty()){
    int del_item=s.pop();
    if(del_item==max.peek())
        max.pop();
}
```

Edit: Both S and Max are of same type i.e Integer.

'S' contains a set of integers and Max tracks the the maximum element of 'S' with each push and pop operation performed on 'S'. I deduced from the question that max is not going to be empty unless 's' is empty. Hence I didn't perform a check if max is empty or not. correct me if i'm wrong. 
Here's the original problem:

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/maximum-element

Here's the whole code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int lines = in.nextInt();
    Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer>();
    Stack<Integer> maxs = new Stack<Integer>();
    int max=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int num=0;
    //maxs.push(max);
    for(int i=0;i<lines;i++){
        int command = in.nextInt();
        switch(command){
            case 1: 
                num= in.nextInt();
                s.push(num);
                if(maxs.isEmpty()||num>=maxs.peek()){
                    maxs.push(num);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if(!s.isEmpty()){
                    //This doesn't work
                    if(s.peek()==max.peek())
                        max.pop();
                    s.pop();
                    }

                    /*--------This works--------
                    int del_item=s.peek();
                    if(del_item==maxs.peek())
                        maxs.pop();
                    s.pop();
                    */

                    /*--------This works--------
                    int del_item=s.pop();
                    if(del_item==maxs.peek())
                        maxs.pop();
                    */
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if(!maxs.isEmpty())
                    System.out.println(maxs.peek());
                //else
                    //System.out.println(max);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What if one (or both) of the stacks are empty?

Comment: Comparing with '==' could be an issue. Especially since your problem goes away when you use an int. Use .equals instead.

Comment: What is contained inside the stacks? You are checking equality by reference with `==`, not with `equals(..)`.

Comment: It would be interesting to show us the whole code (what does these stacks contain?) and the test cases that failed and passed

Comment: Without knowing more about the stacks it's impossible to do anything more than guess.

Comment: From your full code, it seems that you have stacks holding `Integer` objects. Because the stacks contain *object references*, you should use `.equals` rather than `==` to compare the two `Integer` elements as @Jack and @matt suggested.

Comment: @Shlublu hackerrank doesn't reveal all its test cases. I wonder why Code 1 worked for a few test cases while it failed for most of the other testcases.

Comment: Try `if((int)s.peek()==max.peek())` *or* `if(s.peek().intValue()==max.peek())`; see also [JLS-5.1.7. Boxing Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) which says (in part) *If the value `p` being boxed is an integer literal of type int between `-128` and `127` inclusive ([§3.10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1))... then let `a` and `b` be the results of any two boxing conversions of `p`. It is always the case that `a == b`*.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch. That explains a lot! I was wondering why Code 1 worked for few test cases and failed for rest. It is probably because those test cases had numbers ranging from -127 to 127. Thank you.